Different behavior between CreateProcessWithLogonW and CreateProcessWithTokenW
I'd like to know how CreateProcessWithLogonW differs from CreateProcessWithTokenW. I am comparing different methods of starting a process as another user on windows.
With both methods I am able to launch the process, however when using CreateProcessWithTokenW with a (primary)token created by LogonUser, the standard visual styles are dropped. Instead, I am giving an window that looks like a window when configure performance settings for 'best performance' e.g. square windows, no shadows, no rounded buttons.
When I use the same settings to run the process under CreateProcessWithLogonW all the visual styles are working normally, so I don't really understand what the differences are between these two methods.
